# Intuition for the Baker-Cambell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula

Tags: group-theory

The [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula has always fascinated me as for matrices (representations of operators in Quantum mechanics) $A$ and $B$ it tells you: $$e^A e^B = e^{A + B + \frac{1}{2}[A,B]+...}$$ where all the further terms can be calculated by just knowing $A$, $B$ and the special combination $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. I have reproduced the  terms in the expansion till order 4 by just writing down the Taylor expansion that defines them and multiplying them term by term. However, this still doesn't give me any understanding as why all the terms should just depend on this mysterious single combination of $A$, $B$ (called the commutator) apart from $A$, $B$ itself. I know this is a foundational aspect of Lie theory but I was wondering if someone can shed some light on what is the underlying structure of matrices that tells us that only the commutator would suffice to compute the product of two matrices exponentiated?

Or should I just take it as a bit of math magic that it is just the way things are?

Comment: But $[A,B]$ *isn’t* the only commutator in the formula.

Comment: Yeah that's true but you only just need to calculate other commutators. My more general question is what structure of matrices that ensure that terms of any order can simply be written as a nested commutator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much of a visual help this will be. It may be an *abstract* help.
If you're familiar with differential geometry, you will get acquainted with the fact that, abstractly, a commutator *is* a derivative, and a derivative *is* a commutator, in some sense. Both satisfy invariant relations, like,
$$
\left[A,\left[B,C\right]\right]+\left[C,\left[A,B\right]\right]+\left[B,\left[C,A\right]\right]=0
$$
(the Jacobi identity), and,
$$
\left[A,BC\right]=\left[A,B\right]C+B\left[A,C\right]
$$
Also, if,
$$
\left[\left[A,B\right],A\right]=\left[\left[A,B\right],B\right]=0
$$
It's easy to prove,
$$
\left[A,f\left(B\right)\right]=\left[A,B\right]\frac{d}{dB}f\left(B\right)
$$
So, at the very least, we can say that both concepts are very much related. But, as @G.Smith points out, you need successive iterative "derivatives". You need to know how much $\left[A,B\right]$ changes in the "direction" of both $A$ and $B$, etc.

I hope that was in the direction of helping you.